# Can you download your Facebook data through their API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On Facebook there is a "Download your Info" option and you can choose range, format (HTML, JSON) and media quality. Can you do this with the API?

I'm thinking of an iOS app where you could connect with FB, download your data and then visualise it.

Would the above be possible? Or should I change the app so instead of logging in with FB you could just upload your data?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not API for that. I think Facebook has only begrudgingly implemented this to begin with, to satisfy data protection requirements (i.e., people having the right to request what info a company has stored about them), but probably does not want to provide this as a “feature” other apps could easily make use of.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for your response!